# Construct binary tree recursively in cuda

Tags: cuda

I want to build a binary tree in a vector s.t. parent's value would be the sum of its both children. To recursively build the tree in C would look like:

```
int construct(int elements[], int start, int end, int* tree, int index) {
    if (start == end) {
        tree[index] = elements[start];
        return tree[index];
    }
    int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
    tree[index] = construct(elements, start, middle, tree, index*2) +
                  construct(elements, middle, end, tree, index*2+1);
    return tree[index];
}
```

But I don't know how to build it in the CUDA in a parallel way by utilizing the thread. One [reference](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/) I found useful is

> How should we go about parallelizing this kind of recursive algorithm? One way is to use the approach presented by Garanzha et al., which processes the levels of nodes sequentially, starting from the root. The idea is to maintain a growing array of nodes in a breadth-first order, so that every level in the hierarchy corresponds to a linear range of nodes. On a given level, we launch one thread for each node that falls into this range. The thread starts by reading first and last from the node array and calling findSplit(). It then appends the resulting child nodes to the same node array using an atomic counter and writes out their corresponding sub-ranges. This process iterates so that each level outputs the nodes contained on the next level, which then get processed in the next round.

which process each level sequentially and parallelize the nodes at each level. I think it makes total sense, but I don't how to implement that exactly, can somebody give me an idea or example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the indexing scheme described above would work.

Here is a sample code that could work: (though the tree indexing might not suit your needs):

```
__global__ void buildtreelevel(const int* elements, int count, int* tree)
{
    int parentcount = (count + 1) >> 1;
    for (int k = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x ; k < parentcount ; k += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        if ((2*k+1) < count)
            tree[k] = elements[k*2] + elements[k*2+1] ;
        else
            tree[k] = elements[k*2] ;
    }
}
```

This function only processes one tree level at a time. The overall tree size is provided by :

```
int treesize (int count, int& maxlevel)
{
    int res = 1 ;
    while (count > 1)
    {
        count = (count + 1) >> 1 ;
        res += count ;
        ++maxlevel;
    }
    return res ;
}
```

And building the whole tree requires several calls to the buildtreelevel kernel:

```
int buildtree (int grid, int block, const int* d_elements, int count, int** h_tree, int* d_data)
{
    const int* ptr_elements = d_elements ;
    int* ptr_data = d_data ;
    int level = 0 ;
    int levelcount = count ;
    while (levelcount > 1)
    {
        buildtreelevel <<< grid, block >>> (ptr_elements, levelcount, ptr_data) ;
        levelcount = (levelcount + 1) >> 1 ;

        h_tree [level++] = ptr_data ;
        ptr_elements = ptr_data ;
        ptr_data += levelcount ;
    }
    return level ;
}
```

Synchronization only needs to occur at the end as all kernels are executed on stream 0.

```
int main()
{
    int nElements = 10000000 ;
    int* d_elements ;
    int* d_data ;
    int** h_tree ;
    int maxlevel = 1 ;

    cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_elements, nElements * sizeof (int)) ;
    cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_data, treesize(nElements, maxlevel) * sizeof (int)) ;

    h_tree = new int*[maxlevel];

    buildtree (64, 256, d_elements, nElements, h_tree, d_data) ;

    cudaError_t res = cudaDeviceSynchronize() ;
    if (cudaSuccess != res)
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR (%d) : %s \n", res, cudaGetErrorString(res));
    cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

Your tree structure is stored in h_tree, which is a host array of device pointers.

This is not optimal, but might be a good start (using aligned int4 with __ldg) and processing 4 levels at a time might improve performance.